# http interceptors to detect if app is on-/offline (has connection to api) in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, http-caching, angular-http-interceptors

I'm looking for a good solution to detect on-/offline status within my app.
The navigator.onLine apprache is not working, at least with current version of chrome, and I think not reliable. 
App location and server endpoint may differ, so what i really want is to check if the server is offline. I don't mind if the user can use google.com. The app might even be working without internet as long as the server is in the network and responding.

My approach is using an interceptor:

```
$provide.factory('httpOfflineCheckInterceptor', ['$q', '$rootScope', function($q, $rootScope){
    return {
        'response': function(response) {
/** what am I missing here? **/
            return response;
        },
        'responseError': function(rejection) {
            if(rejection.status === -1) {
                $rootScope.appIsOffline = true;
            }
            return rejection;
        }
    }
}]);

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpOfflineCheckInterceptor');
```

So, for each http request made i check the response. Detecting if the app is offline works fine. 
The tricky thing is, check if the app is online again. 'response', I do cache http request. Status of some responses is 200 even if i'm offline, because they are cached. So cached request or getting templates should be ignored when checking if the app is online again.

Comment: Wouldn't app be offline if ajax request gets timeout?

Comment: Yes and no. Since the cached request will not time out. App might still be offline.
What is a good approache for handeling a http timeout?

Comment: You could have a small service/ajax request that will periodically hit the server, other than that I can't think of valid way to check offline/online status of app and for the cached calls, if it's cached and it should be why worry if the app is offline?

Comment: main reason: display a small badge so the user is informed the app may not work as usually.

Comment: Then heart beat is your solution, a small service that will do very simple xhr requests in intervals (or rather timeouts as it's better for the purpose - it will not overlap like it can with interval) and store the status of last call

Comment: I wanted to avoid that, but I'll give it a try.
Thank you for your fast replys-